# How to get cpu load (%), overall and per core, in Java?

Tags: java, monitoring, cpu

I need to run a cpu load monitor on a server. I'd like to create a separate process for that purpose, instead of instrumenting a messy blob of server application code. The question is simple though:

How can I get the system cpu usage (overall and per core, in percentage) using Java?

I've checked `OperatingSystemMXBean.getSystemLoadAverage()`, but it gives me the average system cpu load of the last minute, which is too long for me. I need to monitor the load every second (or less). Besides this one give the overall system cpu load.

Finally, is it possible to get the cpu usage of threads that belong to another Java process?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `mpstat` on Linux in `Runtime.exec()` and parse the output.  I don't know if there is anything similar on Windows.

```
$ mpstat -A 10
Linux 3.8.0-27-generic (peter-hex)  08/09/13    _x86_64_    (12 CPU)

21:04:39     CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
21:04:49     all    0.27    0.00    0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.55
21:04:49       0    0.40    0.00    0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.40
21:04:49       1    0.80    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.70
21:04:49       2    0.50    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.10
21:04:49       3    0.80    0.00    0.50    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.70
21:04:49       4    0.10    0.00    0.20    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.70
21:04:49       5    0.70    0.00    0.40    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   98.90
21:04:49       6    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.90
21:04:49       7    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
21:04:49       8    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
21:04:49       9    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
21:04:49      10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
21:04:49      11    0.00    0.00    0.10    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00   99.90
```

> is it possible to get the cpu usage of threads that belong to another Java process?

Yes, you can use `ps -eLf` and see all threads on the system.  This gives you the CPU used since starting. (From which you can calculate utilisation if you want)

Comment: Right, it's not very platform independent, but works for now. How would I call mpstat with Runtime.exec and parse the output though? Could you please add code showing that?

Comment: I would use a BufferedReader and split("\\s+") each lines to get the words. System monitoring is system dependent fundamentally. e.g. getSystemLoadAverage() doesn't work on Windows either.

Comment: How do I get get the current load of the system? If I call `mpstat -P ALL`, I get the statistics since the start of the machine.